# Entity Framework - Store Password

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, passwords

I'm learning WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework and just making a test project (For learning purposes). Currently a user can go on the app and "sign up".
I've currently been able store and retrieve data from a database, which is cool.
The next step for me is to give the ability to have a password for the user, something that can be encrypted and decrypted. The problem I'm having is trying to used a PasswordBox, I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I've read some articles about PasswordHelper classes and such, but there isn't anything that goes step-by-step that I can follow. As far as I can tell, this can't be done following MVVM, so that's fine, I'm just finding it difficult to break MVVM.

If anybody can help push me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: The standard MVC project templates contain a Login form.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? WPF, MVVM or storing the password?
BTW: Passwords should be stored as cryptographically strong hash (which is not decryptable)

Comment: @HenkHolterman but MVC is Web-Technics, this question is Desktop-Application related

Comment: Where is your database, remote?